# Making a map of composite types typescript

Tags: typescript

I was working on translating some C# code where they used dictionaries of Vector2 to string:

I made a simple test case [(see here on .NET fiddle)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LvAPZh) to try to convert to JS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

Dictionary<Vector2, string> hd = new()
{
    {new(0,0), "Zero" },
    {new(0,1), "{0, 1}"},
    {new(1,0), "{1, 0}"},
    {new(1,1), "{1, 1}"}
};
foreach (var (key, value) in hd)
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {{{key.x}, {key.y}}}. Value: {value}");

public record Vector2 (double x, double y);
```

I tried to translate to typescript and I wanted to make a general dictionary type that would work on any type where you could put a function that would translate to and from a value that you could put in a JS `Map`.

I made a hasher type for the converter to a mappable type:

```
interface Hasher<T, Hash>
{
    GetHashCode(value: T ): Hash;
    GetValue   (hash:Hash): T;
}
```

and a Vector2 type:

```
interface Vector2 { x:number; y:number; }
```

I made an abstract type as follows:

```
abstract class Dictionary<TKey, TValue, Hash>
{
    ['constructor']: typeof Dictionary & Hasher<TKey, Hash>;
    impl: Map<Hash, TValue> = new Map();
}
```

and made a simple add and iterator:

```
Add(key: TKey, value: TValue)
{
    this.impl.set(this.constructor.GetHashCode(key), value);
}
*[Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<[TKey, TValue]>
{
    for (let [key, value] of this.impl)
        yield [this.constructor.GetValue(key), value];
}
```

I made a function to convert a Vector2 to and from a hex string:

```
static Vector2 = class<TValue> extends Dictionary<Vector2, TValue, string>
{
    static GetHashCode(value: Vector2): string
    {
        let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16);
        let arr = new Float64Array(buffer);
        arr[0] = value.x;
        arr[1] = value.y;
        return [...new Uint8Array(buffer)].map(x => x.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
    }
    static GetValue(hash: string): Vector2
    {
        let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16);
        let u8arr  = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for (let n = 0; n < 16; n++) u8arr[n] = +('0x'+hash.substr(n*2, 2));
        let arr = new Float64Array(buffer);
        return {x: arr[0], y: arr[1]};
    }
}
```

and I wanted to add some type checks to ensure that my Dictionary implementations were implementing the required methods:

```
// Type Checks:
{
    const Dictionary$string: Hasher<string, string>  = Dictionary.string ;
    const Dictionary$int:    Hasher<number, number>  = Dictionary.int    ;
    const Dictionary$Vector2:Hasher<Vector2, string> = Dictionary.Vector2;
}
```

My question was whether there is a better way to go about doing these type checks (maybe one that doesn't just generate redundant JS). This is the best way I could find.

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you want `getValue()`, or why you're bothering with abstract classes. I'd be inclined to write it [like this](https://tsplay.dev/w26MVw) if I wanted such functionality; what you're calling a "hash" is a unique string representation (you could make it generic, but it has to be something where `===` works, so you're pretty much looking at `string` or `number` or `bigint`, and `string` works well for all three of those), and you can just store your entries in the inner map.  By having the `Dict` class ask for the id function in the constructor, there's no type check to do.

Comment: I'm happy to write the above code up as an answer, but maybe I'm not really understanding the question. Is this just a code review question (in which case maybe you're looking for [code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typescript) instead?) or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @jcalz, I like your code. If you leave it as an answer, I would accept. I was just wondering specifically about a better way to type checks but your code is good for my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question as asked is probably "anything else you do to verify the types of those `static` properties will be more involved than what you're already doing, so you might as well keep doing that".

TypeScript doesn't have a simple way to verify that a value is assignable to some type without generally *widening* it to that type.  You'd like to say something like

```
static Vector2 = class <TValue> extends Dictionary<Vector2, TValue, string> {
  /* snip */
} verify Hasher<Vector2, string>;
```

where `verify` is some type-system-only alternative to a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) which doesn't affect the inferred type of the `Vector2` property, but will produce a compiler error if that inferred type is not assignable to `Hasher<Vector2, string>`. There is a longstanding open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481) asking for such a feature, but for now it doesn't exist.

You can implement something yourself which works like it, but it has a (minor) runtime component and is complicated by lack of language support for *partial type parameter inference* of the sort asked for in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  Here's one possible approach:

```
static Vector2 = verify(null! as Hasher<Vector2, string>,
    class <TValue> extends Dictionary<Vector2, TValue, string> {
      /* snip */
    }
);
```

where `verify` looks like

```
const verify = <T, U extends T>(dummy: T, val: U) => val;
```

So the compiler will check the type of `val` to make sure it's assignable to the type of `dummy`, and it returns `val` without widening it.  Conceptually there's no reason why the compiler should need the `dummy` value, but you want the compiler to infer `U` while letting you specify `T`, and there's no direct support for that.

Anyway, you could define and call `verify()` instead of creating `Dictionary$Vector2`, but I don't know that it's worth it.

So that's the basic answer.

---

As I alluded to in the comments, though, I don't think I'd try to implement `Dictionary` the way you have.  The issues I spot:

- what you are calling a "hash" code is really an identifier.  Hash codes are not meant to *identify* a piece of data; you use hash codes to quickly split things up into buckets, with the acknowledgement that more than one thing might end up in the same bucket.  For `Dictionary` it would be very bad if different keys ever had the same hash code.  Instead, the intent here is that your identifier function should define what key equality means: two keys are equal if and only if they produce the same identifier.
- Instead of allowing the identifier to be of any type, I would be inclined to pick `string` and stick with it.  Whatever you choose needs to be comparable with `===`, since that's more or less how [`Map` key equality works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#key_equality).
- I don't see much use for `GetValue` and it could even be harmful.  TypeScript uses a [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) in which you are allowed to extend `Vector2` with extra properties.  A value of `interface Vector2WithCheese extends Vector2 { cheese: true }` is also a value of type `Vector2`; if I put a `Vector2WithCheese` into my dictionary, I expect that `Vector2WithCheese` to come out; not some freshly-created `Vector2`.  Even without subtyping, breaking reference equality on the key could surprise users and doesn't seem to buy you much.   Instead, I'd suggest holding both the original key and the value in the inner `Map`.
- I'm a bit wary of code that declares the `constructor` property of a class; I suppose this is to work around the lack of strongly-typed constructors, as per [microsoft/TypeScript#3841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841).  I don't know how helpful it is to require that the constructor itself have certain static properties, especially `abstract` static properties which are not really supported, as per [microsoft/TypeScript#34516](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34516).  There might be some benefit to ensuring that a whole class will calculate key equality the same way, but I don't know that it's worth the complexity around strongly typing the static side of the class.  Instead, I'd probably just pass the key-identifier function as a parameter to the class constructor and allow for the possibility that two instances of `Dictionary` might compare keys in different ways.
- Then instead of storing the subclasses of `Dictionary` as static properties of `Dictionary` itself, I'd probably just make regular subclasses where the key identifier function is set a particular way.  Once you do this, the need for type checking the subclasses is gone.

The code could look something like this:

```
class Dict<K, V> {
    private map = new Map<string, [K, V]>()
    constructor(public toIdString: (k: K) => string, entries?: Iterable<[K, V]>) {
        if (entries) {
            for (const [k, v] of entries) {
                this.set(k, v);
            }
        }
    }
    set(k: K, v: V) {
        this.map.set(this.toIdString(k), [k, v]);
        return this;
    }
    get(k: K): V | undefined {
        return this.map.get(this.toIdString(k))?.[1]
    }
    [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<[K, V]> {
        return this.map.values();
    }
}
```

and

```
class Vector2Dict<V> extends Dict<Vector2, V> {
    constructor(entries?: Iterable<[Vector2, V]>) {
        super(v => "" + v.x + "," + v.y, entries);
    }
}
```

And you can verify that it behaves as desired:

```
const hd = new Vector2Dict<string>([
    [{ x: 0, y: 0 }, "Zero"],
    [{ x: 0, y: 1 }, "{0, 1}"],
    [{ x: 1, y: 0 }, "{1, 0}"],
    [{ x: 1, y: 1 }, "{1, 1}"]
]);
for (const [key, value] of hd) {
    console.log(`Key: {${key.x}, ${key.y}}. Value: ${value}`);
}

/*
Key: {0, 0}. Value: Zero
Key: {0, 1}. Value: {0, 1}
Key: {1, 0}. Value: {1, 0}
Key: {1, 1}. Value: {1, 1}
*/

console.log(hd.get({ x: 0, y: 0 })?.toUpperCase()); // ZERO
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBJwM4AtoB4AqANGplgHzIDeAUMncgOIRjrYDCA9gCYQAUAbnAA2AVwgAuZPgCUk1lgDctekzAA1YWN5ZSc0rKlKAvtWqhIsRCjUQEYDlABMVZAA9JIEQFsARtAXIAJ4e3n5QASbUCBwgGGDI-NDAMIHIALzIBMQAqsgQrpAgXBhSZLxc3l7BUsSCQpLZ0ukUdUrUcD5xUIjxCEKYJQAiwHbAMXBQgQQA0hCBxPgaohDE8mTUNPTIANoA5NGxYFAidg67ALqSYIEADhAcMMjDo+OTyABkJNh4+LPzX+QlFtgF4bvVkABZOA3XDyBZLMQUDIgCAAd0h0N40jaWwAglwuLwANZzSS-Oa1TQSKQIiBNTZbehgLDADAAOhBYLZGGYvGZrLZBy6J3sUDZqnknB4xLm0kpy2xyjoJi2ACptgBlQK+DhCDkWOCi85YyQASQNotw23J-0WVPOFAZjOQMAcyF4QmYOxJ-zqYnOyAeyH57M5QmkSud9ECwAgQi4OxDgpiwtOYtUtJlgTlCXtQPokS2cUNI2QNjTzgyiSgyUCvE8QiEAEJkJgAXhy6LHMQuqAAOZkQiRrZ9AaZO3LCj5QrFJ4jMBjEATKadhzdmlUntHfvrKNUYdR4sLhCMZiS7h8P3U1dOAy9kB9-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-wkhqOH8FJvz3K8kmasa2jfbEjm2yxwk5zx1Gh3HcGLIYA9Kd0H2vJErrIXIAAPsgIhFBAMCgBACbhXuDfCU3AoFx35nFxw6s6WXFfSGbbJsecycy5q2o+Lq+rQIaDjGgY5rH5a4usw6tMHYJ0-59CbJXhgWKt5Ghb0F9P9faYwLgGgPAMmoU76MncL+UI0Ahx7mqJ4Xw0BP7-zpv0BmZZbBdkhsjKcBQ3aziwSjMs7M9xyxFA4V27tzaW2PtbCAVpCH2zILnZ8GARB3AgvwDSAAiLhg0EgMT4VwwgvChr8G4sQEOptPYfy2F-Og-ssAJlWugisWCgplG2LvU6ECqJXUkFRO6xAuEAC1oAcC4ecGBUZtjaP0XoxqhjkBcMoLoxqRgLFWOdDYs6jV7EGKMEYygkFiBUXcZYrRPjglBEkJBRxziomQTCZGWuvFfa8H9lXCknF-SBkeIo5hI4Uy6ggGyTC5cAAGfxJCUBhpQH0DEAnIFqfUwIRgjBsjLFSSQtSrxGHKaVORyAPqqkjFUqgrjQkdNpJIUxUAOCjNJOM4giSpldKWW4hZ1QgkhPaZ05Y1SomhM2Qc5ZuzplUASS9VUH1kHyKKZ6UpHBy6KLZPPXgtjkCuOqP49eWkODZBuOwtgmA+ALSGd9YxABRAASgAeWoEYIAA)