# Merge an array of objects by a shared prop value

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array of objects like:

```
let data = [
    {account: 1, page: 1, amount: 123},
    {account: 1, page: 1, items: {desc: 'test', date: '12/31/2021'}}
    {account: 1, page: 2, amount: 789}
    {account: 2, page: 1, amount: 456}
]
```

I want to be able to merge the objects that have matching **"account" and "page" values**. So I'd like the return object to be

```
[
   {account:1, page:1, amount: 123, items: {desc: 'test', date: '12/31/2021'}},
   {account: 1, page: 2, amount: 789}
   {account: 2, page: 1, amount: 456}
]
```

If I have a third object matching the merge criteria:

```
{account: 1, page: 1, items: {desc: 'another one', date: '8/2/2021'}}
```

I'd like that to be merged so the final object will be:

```
[
   {account:1, page:1, amount: 123, items: [{desc: 'test', date: '12/31/2021'}, {desc: 'another one', date: '8/2/2021'}]},
   {account: 1, page: 2, amount: 789}
   {account: 2, page: 1, amount: 456}
]
```

I need this to work for a variable length array of objects. I've started writing a naive solution but I was trying to avoid inefficient loops. Is there an efficient way of going about this? I was looking at [lodash's merge](https://lodash.com/docs/#merge), but I'm not sure that can be applied here

Comment: Can you show us the "naive solution"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
const data = [
  {account: 1, page: 1, amount: 123},
  {account: 1, page: 1, items: {desc: 'test', date: '12/31/2021'}},
  {account: 1, page: 2, amount: 789},
  {account: 2, page: 1, amount: 456},
];

const map = new Map();

for (const obj of data) {
  const key = `${obj.account}-${obj.page}`;
  const existing = map.get(key) ?? {};
  const items = [...existing.items ?? [], ...obj.items ? [obj.items] : []];
  map.set(key, {...existing, ...obj, items: items.length > 0 ? items : undefined});
}

console.log([...map.values()]);
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I see that this would make it so it merges the matching objects together, but it seems that if there is a third object that matches the criteria, it's "items" object will overwrite the previous merge, instead of adding to it. So I'm trying to see if there is a way for those items to be added to an array of objects as they're all merged. Still looking into that, but any tips are appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: @Cineno28 just replace `{...existing, ...item}` with `{...existing, ...item, items: [...existing.items, ...item.items]}`

Answer (score 1):

This assumes `account` and `page` are integers less than 2^26 and should perform well.

```js
let data = [
    {account: 1, page: 1, amount: 123},
    {account: 1, page: 1, items: {desc: 'test', date: '12/31/2021'}},
    {account: 1, page: 2, amount: 789},
    {account: 2, page: 1, amount: 456}
]

debugger;

let byAccountsAndPages = new Map();

for (let json of data)
{
    let id = json.account * (1 << 26) + json.page;
    let existingJson = byAccountsAndPages.get(id);
    if (existingJson !== undefined)
        json = {...existingJson, ...json};
    byAccountsAndPages.set(id, json);
}

console.log(Array.from(byAccountsAndPages.values()));
```

It creates a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which is an insertion-order list optimized for looking up a key. The key will be a unique combination of `account` and `page` assuming they are both below 2^26. The reason I chose 2^26 is because the max safe int is 2^53 so to combine two into one requires 2^26 numbers. A `Map` can contain many different key types one of which is integers. If they are not integers you could try converting them into unique strings as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67780926/making-a-map-of-composite-types-typescript).

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! Please see my comment to jsejcksn on his answer. It looks like both of these answers will cause the merge to overwrite the "items" object of the previous merge. Is there a way you'd suggest extending this to allow the merge to keep the items objects of all merges, and just add them to an "items" array of objects? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Cineno28 just replace `{...existingJson, ...json}` with `{...existingJson, ...json, items: [...existingJson.items, ...json.items]}`

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response! I just tried this but I'm getting an error saying that it's not iterable. Would my initial objects need to change their structure to work with this?

Comment: @Cineno28 oh sorry I made a mistake it should be `{...existingJson, ...json, items: {...existingJson.items, ...json.items}}`. I assumed `items` was an array.

Comment: Yeah 'items' is coming in as an object, but I'm hoping the final merged result will store them in an array of objects. That change seemed to fix the error, but it still doesn't add the other merged items object. I'm going to keep playing with it. I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: If you want it an array of objects do, `{...existingJson, ...json, items: [existingJson.items, json.items]}`